# Windows Phone 7:Transfer some data from first page to seond page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

A have a two pages:

FirstPage — some data;
SecondPage — three TextBlocks (they need to pass some data);

but transmitted in only one, how to transfer to other?

FirstPage one parametr transfer:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Total.xaml?Pay=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(logic3.ToString()), UriKind.Relative));
```

SecondPage:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Pay")) 
            {
                paymentTextBlock.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["Pay"].ToString();
            }
```

How to pass other data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the others to the end of your Uri using ampersands `&`.

```cs
NavigationService
  .Navigate(new Uri("/Total.xaml?Pay=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(logic3.ToString()) + 
                    "&Parm2=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(someOtherField.ToString(), 
                     UriKind.Relative));
```